# .htaccess non-www redirect to subfolder of root folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl

I know this topic is discussed very frequently on the site. 
But i am facing the same and cant get resolved this issue related to .htaccess reqrite.

Current scenario is I am forcing to use www. to my domain and redirect to sub-directory and use as a domain root.

I have following entry in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subfolder/index.php
```

All is working fine by forcing to use www. for the doamin and redirecting to sub-folder

As I have ssl certificate which is for domain.com, www.domain.com is not acceptable for ssl certificate.

Now i need non-www forcefully and redirect the primary domain to a sub-directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /subfolder/index.php [L]
```

Comment: is it possible to do this RewriteEngine subfolder in this case?

Comment: or RewriteEngine /subfolder/

Comment: You need to actually use `RewriteBase /subfolder/` below `RewriteEngine On`. For more specific problem feel free to post a question.

Comment: here is the question. I really appretiate if you look at it. Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800530/redirect-non-www-and-https-to-subfolder-of-root-folder