# redirect non-www and https to subfolder of the root

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to make test env for this website. I have the same website on live and it is working.

I am trying to redirect the request to do the redirect to this usbfolder(OPS). 
This is what I wrote  so far but it sounds it is redirecting to root.
If I remove the https it works but with https it doesn't. It sounds it's redirected to root

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /OPS/


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.domain\.co\.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/OPS/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /OPS/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.domain\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /OPS/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Need some clarity on what you're trying to do here? Also check what is DocumentRoot of `https`, is it same as `http` site's `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: DocumentRoot is /var/www/websites/dev it is working with http but again it not working with https

Comment: I asked much more than that. I cannot help unless I understand your problem.

Comment: I am trying to make test env for this website.

Comment: Sorry but your rules have no reference to `https` and I cannot solve a problem by my imagination. You need to provide much more details like location of this .htacces, `<VirtualHost` entries of `http` and `https` site, URL's you are entering in browser and the errors you're getting etc etc.

Comment: `If I remove the https it works` - Show the line before you removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your concern. As @anubhava mentioned the problem was with my document root. We revert back the htaccess to what ever it was. and overwrite the DOCUMENT_ROOT in top of the page and it is working:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/var/www/websites/dev') !== false) {
    // OPS(sub-folder) 
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .= '/OPS'; 
}
```

I would like to over-write document root in htaccess if it would have been possible. any way this is the answer I came up with so far.